# using time zone in pandas to_datetime

Tags: pandas, timezone

I have time from epochs timestamps
I use `data.Time_req = pd.to_datetime(data.Time_req)`
But I get UTC time, I need +5:30 from the given time. How do I tell pandas to use `'IST'` timezone or just `5hrs 30 mins` further to the time it currently shows me. eg. `7 hrs` should become `12:30 hrs` and so on.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

You can use [`tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_localize.html) to set the timezone to `UTC`/+0000, and then [`tz_convert`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.tz_convert.html) to add the timezone you want:

```
start = pd.to_datetime('2015-02-24')
rng = pd.date_range(start, periods=10)

df = pd.DataFrame({'Date': rng, 'a': range(10)})  

df.Date = df.Date.dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
print (df)
                       Date  a
0 2015-02-24 05:30:00+05:30  0
1 2015-02-25 05:30:00+05:30  1
2 2015-02-26 05:30:00+05:30  2
3 2015-02-27 05:30:00+05:30  3
4 2015-02-28 05:30:00+05:30  4
5 2015-03-01 05:30:00+05:30  5
6 2015-03-02 05:30:00+05:30  6
7 2015-03-03 05:30:00+05:30  7
8 2015-03-04 05:30:00+05:30  8
9 2015-03-05 05:30:00+05:30  9
```

[Working with time zones](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#working-with-time-zones).

If need add `Timedelta` only:

```
df.Date = df.Date + pd.Timedelta('05:30:00')
print (df)
                 Date  a
0 2015-02-24 05:30:00  0
1 2015-02-25 05:30:00  1
2 2015-02-26 05:30:00  2
3 2015-02-27 05:30:00  3
4 2015-02-28 05:30:00  4
5 2015-03-01 05:30:00  5
6 2015-03-02 05:30:00  6
7 2015-03-03 05:30:00  7
8 2015-03-04 05:30:00  8
9 2015-03-05 05:30:00  9
```

**NOTE:** Adding `Timedelta` will change the epoch timestamp associated with the `datetime` object. This may not be desired for many applications.

Comment: Available timezones could be found by `pytz.all_timezones` command.

Answer (score 8):

#### From unix epoch timestamps

```
timestamps = [1656285319, 1656285336, 1656285424]

pd.to_datetime(timestamps, unit='s', utc=True).map(lambda x: x.tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata'))
```

outputs:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2022-06-27 04:45:19+05:30', '2022-06-27 04:45:36+05:30',
               '2022-06-27 04:47:04+05:30'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns, Asia/Kolkata]', freq=None)
```

##### All timezones

```
import pytz
pytz.all_timezones
```

[full list here](https://gist.github.com/eusoubrasileiro/2a442218ecf634ed5b5919a9783ddb7d)

Answer (score 5):

The following worked for me:

```
df['Local_Time'] = pd.to_datetime(df,unit='s', utc=True)\
                      .map(lambda x: x.tz_convert('America/Chicago'))
```

[This is the list of the name of timezones in pytz.](https://gist.github.com/heyalexej/8bf688fd67d7199be4a1682b3eec7568)

Hope this helps someone!

Answer (score 2):

These .map suggestions resulted in
pandas to_datetime 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'map' errors.

What worked in my case is:

```
df.insert(0, 'uploadtimestamp', pd.to_datetime('now').replace(microsecond=0))

df['uploadtimestamp'] = df['uploadtimestamp'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern')
```

or

```
df.insert(0, 'uploadtimestamp',pd.to_datetime('now').replace(microsecond=0))

df['uploadtimestamp'] = df['uploadtimestamp'].dt.tz_localize('UTC').dt.tz_convert('US/Eastern').apply(lambda x: x.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'))
```

if want the timestamp column to be a string.