# Why getting epoch time conversion wrong? What is the right and quickest way?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, time, epoch

**My objective** : convert this time stamp in the quickest way.

```
{'timestamp': 1533203940000, 'open': 564.1, 'high': 567.55, 'low': 563.4, 'close': 564.45, 'volume': 522096, 'cp': 564.45}
```

into "2018-08-02 15:29:00" (This is what I should be getting)

However, I am not getting it to convert right.Hours is wrong. **Maybe it is something to do with timezones ?** I tried....

```
n=np.array([1533203940]).astype('datetime64[s]')
```

I get :

```
['2018-08-02T09:59:00']
```

And then....

```
time.gmtime(1533203940)
```

is also wrong....

```
time.struct_time(tm_year=2018, tm_mon=8, tm_mday=2, tm_hour=9, 
tm_min=59, tm_sec=0, tm_wday=3, tm_yday=214, tm_isdst=0)
```

Pandas is also not right.

```
pd.to_datetime(1533203940,unit='s')
```

it gives....

```
2018-08-02 09:59:00
```

Only datetime gets it right !!!

```
datetime.fromtimestamp(1533203940)
```

which gives..

```
2018-08-02 15:29:00
```

Where are others going wrong ? Without an answer I might get my future calculations wrong and I may not even realize it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks you need something like this

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'], unit= 'ms').dt.tz_localize('utc') \
    .dt.tz_convert(tz='USE YOUR TIME ZONE HERE').apply \
    (lambda x: datetime.replace(x, tzinfo=None))
```

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply but I was getting some errors and I tried this : df = pd.to_datetime(t, unit= 'ms').tz_localize('UTC').tz_convert('Asia/Kolkata')
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826388/using-time-zone-in-pandas-to-datetime#42826430

Comment: Another way is to do pd.DateOffset(hours=5,minutes=30) to get to required time zone.