# Pandas | time conversions

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timestamp

I have a question concerning time conversion in Python/Pandas. The following is not entirely clear to me.

```
t1 = datetime.datetime(2021,9,15,6,0)
tt1 = t1.timestamp()
pd.to_datetime(tt1,unit='s')
[1] Timestamp('2021-09-15 04:00:00')
```

What do I have to change to get the following result:

```
[1] Timestamp('2021-09-15 06:00:00')
```

Thank you!

Comment: What is your timezone? GMT+2?

Comment: Timezone is Europe/Vienna. Currenty because of daylight saving time the offset is GMT+1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to set the timezone to UTC in `t1` because you use naive datetime and when you use `pd.to_datetime` with a float, Pandas assumes the number is relative to `1970-01-01 00:00:00+0000` and not from your local time zone. There is no information about your timezone in 1631678400.0.

```
t1 = datetime.datetime(2021,9,15,6,0)
tt1 = t1.replace(tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc).timestamp()
print(pd.to_datetime(tt1,unit='s'))

# Output
2021-09-15 06:00:00
```

Answer (score 1):

You can offset your time difference to GMT with

```py
pd.to_datetime(tt1, unit='s') + pd.Timedelta('02:00:00')
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826388/using-time-zone-in-pandas-to-datetime) for more details.