# How to calculate minutes passed since given date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, timedelta

I have a dataframe that has a column named `Created_Timestamp`. I want to see how many minutes passed since that given date. I want to know dwell time in minutes from the column `Created_Timestamp`.

```
 Created_Timestamp          Dwell Time
 2022-04-25 00:33:33.482      842 min 
 2022-04-25 08:30:52.904      364 min 
 2022-04-25 12:11:04.624      144 min
```

Dwell Time will be from current time.

```
curtime = dt.now()
df['Dwell Time'] = curtime - df['Created_Timestamp']
```

This did not work as I intended. How can I do this correctly?

Comment: How exactly did it work differently than intended?

Comment: Instead of giving me minutes its giving me something like this -1 days +22:16:40.261724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

curtime = datetime.now()

qqq = pd.to_datetime(df['Created_Timestamp'])
aaa = pd.to_datetime(curtime)
ttt = (aaa - qqq).dt.total_seconds()/60
df['Dwell Time'] = ttt
```

Output

```
         Created_Timestamp  Dwell  Time   Dwell Time
0  2022-04-25 00:33:33.482    842  min   1463.694005
1  2022-04-25 08:30:52.904    364  min    986.370305
2  2022-04-25 12:11:04.624    144   min   766.174972
```

Comment: its giving typeerror for me TypeError: strptime() argument 1 must be str, not Timestamp

This is what i have on Created_Timestamp
df['Created_Timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Created_Timestamp'],unit = 'ms')

Comment: What type of data do you have: print(type(df['Created_Timestamp'][0]))#<class 'str'>

Comment: <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>

Comment: Updated the code, run the one at the bottom and let me know the result. If it doesn't work, try of df['Created_Timestamp'] instead 'qqq'.

Comment: Its running but minutes are way too off. may be because of utc time. the site reports on utc time and code i have is on est time

Comment: Perhaps. I also have a different time from you. Updated the code, now the current time with hours and minutes, maybe that's the problem? Run the updated code.

Comment: If you say that you have different times. Then you need to find out the difference in minutes, either plus or minus it, in order to synchronize. In general, if I helped, I would grateful for your vote for the answer)

Comment: The output i am getting is   2022-04-25 15:51:52.556      15.118676  but on the website i have   04-25-2022 11:51:52 249  somehow i need to change my Create_Timestamp to 04-25-2022 11:51:52

Comment: Don't you know how to add four hours to your data?

Comment: trying to add..not working

Comment: Take 240 minutes away from your minutes, if that's the case?

Comment: actually i needed to add. Looks now it works now Thanks

Comment: And don't forget that American time is translated in spring and autumn on different dates with European. It is better, of course, to take into account time zones programmatically, read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826388/using-time-zone-in-pandas-to-datetime)