# How to convert object to datetime (in North American timezone)

Tags: python

I have downloaded the data from the database and received the column with date and time as an object:

```
2022-08-24 21:17:34-04:00

2022-11-21 23:48:42-05:00

Name: timestamp, dtype: object
```

When I try to convert it to datetime with (pd.to_datetime), I still receive an object in responcse.

```
pd.to_datetime(test['timestamp'])
```

But when I use **utc=True** param, then it becomes datetime, but it transfers to utc timezone.
I need to work with the original time.

What should I do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [using time zone in pandas to\_datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42826388/using-time-zone-in-pandas-to-datetime)